# Org-capture menu from within helm

Tags: helm, org-capture, helm-sources

I have started using `org-capture` extensively, and now have capture lists for just about everything: books to read, movies to rent, articles to write, research topics, business ideas – you name it.

The trouble is, my `org-capture` menu is filling up fast, and I am now starting to run out of letters in the alphabet to represent all my lists!

So I am wondering - is there an `org-capture` module for `helm` that will display a source with all my capture lists and then let me start typing the name of the list, to narrow down my selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, and is called `helm-org`. The command you want is called `helm-org-capture-templates`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @jagrg!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generic `org-capture` template per file and use `yasnippet` inside org mode with the actual template you want in your file. You can use completion to search for names, it's not helm, but still it doesn't seem bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after here is just refiling your captured template. I use these variables so that when I refile, I am asked which heading in which file I want to put it under. Helm can complete in that query.

```
    (setq org-refile-targets          '((org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 2))
          org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
```